# Can't use glGenBuffers in .h file C++

Tags: c++, opengl, namespaces, header-files, glad

I'm trying to learn OpenGL in C++. To clean up my code I was trying to create an header file with all variables, which decribe objects, in it. This header looks something like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

namespace data {

    ...

    float fragments[] = {...}
    int indices[] = {...}

    ...

}
```

I would like to add to this namespace also VAOs and VBOs, but as soon as I try to implement them using `glGenBuffers` and `glGenVertexArray`:

```
unsigned int VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
```

the IDE (Visual Studio) points me an error out, which says "this declaration doesn't include storage class or type identifier" (referred to `glGenBuffer` function; my editor is set to Italian, hence my translation might not be berfect). I've also tried to add a class inside this namesace (even if in my starting plans I wanted to avoid this approach):

```
#include <...>

namespace data {


    class Data {
 
        public:
            unsigned int VBO;
            glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)

    };
    

}
```

This time the error I get reads: "Missing explicit type. It is going to be used int" (referred to `glGenBuffers` function; holds what I wrote before: the translation might not be perfect, but I think it is understandable).
As a last attempt, I've tried to implement the namespace in the `main.cpp` file too, under the `main` function. The error I get is the same as the first one, but if I use these function calls inside main, they work. I've also already written some other classes, such as `shader.h` or `camera.h` following [this](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Lighting-maps) guide, and there I was able (using necessary includes such as `glad/glad.h`) to use `gl*` functions such as `glCreateShader`, `glCreateProgram`, `glAttachShader` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet from OP:

```
namespace data {


    class Data {
 
        public:
            unsigned int VBO;
            glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)

    };

}
```

This is a syntax error. `glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)` is a function call outside a function body block scope. You have to move it e.g. into the constructor of `class Data`. At best, you could put it into a lambda which is used as an initializer of `Data::VBO`:

```
namespace data {


    class Data {
 
        public:
            unsigned int VBO
              = []() { unsigned int VBO; glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); return VBO; }();

    };
    

}
```

Looks a bit convoluted? As `glGenBuffers()` expects a pointer, the *local variable* `VBO` has to be used inside the lambda. It's value is `return`ed to initialize the *member var.* `VBO`. Of course, I could've given the local var. yet another name…

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37b102ab07082e55)

Comment: You're saying I can't use function call outside functions? You know I'm coming from a python background and this sounds a little awkward for me...

Comment: @Luke__ You hardly can apply knowledge from Python to C++. These are different languages. Yes, it's allowed in Python, and no, it's not allowed in C++. (And, this is btw. not the only difference between the two languages.) ;-)

Comment: I understand! Thank you so much for your time and effort in answering me! Have a good day!